# Merging two pandas DataFrames based on numerical column with different value, preserving unique variables from each

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to merge two DataFrames where the id needs to match, the categorical variables from each DataFrame is preserved, and the sum total for each id/category is preserved. Sorry if the wording is bit unclear, essentially I am starting with two Dataframes that each assign a category to some number of IDs:

```
>>> print(df_a)
  id   cat_a  sum_a
0  A    blue    800
1  B    blue    500
2  B   green    500
3  C  yellow    550
4  D     red   1000

>>> print(df_b)
  id     cat_b  sum_b
0  A    square    700
1  A  triangle    100
2  B    circle    700
3  B  triangle    300
4  C  pentagon    550
5  D      line    800
6  D  triangle    200
```

Looking at id=B, in cat_a 500/1000 are blue, 500/1000 are green, and in cat_b 700/1000 are circles, 300/1000 are triangles.

Both DataFrames have the same totals for each ID:

```
>>>print(df_a.groupby('id')['sum_a'].sum() == df_b.groupby('id')['sum_b'].sum())
id
A    True
B    True
C    True
D    True
```

I want to create a new DataFrame, df_c, which combines the categories and distributes the sums in sum_c, such that the original sums are still in accordance with their original DataFrames. Here is a handmade example:

```
>>> print(df_c)
  id   cat_a     cat_b  sum_c
0  A    blue    square    700
1  A    blue  triangle    100
2  B    blue    circle    500
3  B   green    circle    200
4  B   green  triangle    300
5  C  yellow  pentagon    550
6  D     red      line    800
7  D     red  triangle    200
```

I can confirm df_c is correct by performing a groupby back into it's constituent Dataframes, and checking it matches the original:

```
>>> df_c2a = df_c.groupby(['id', 'cat_a'], as_index=False)['sum_c'].sum()
>>> print(np.all(df_a.values == df_c2a.values))
True

>>> df_c2b = df_c.groupby(['id', 'cat_b'], as_index=False)['sum_c'].sum()
>>> print(np.all(df_b.values == df_c2b.values))
True
```

Currently, I am stumped as to how I might create the third DataFrame, df_c out of the first two. Any suggestions on the best way to accomplish this?

---

I've tried doing a left merge on 'id', however I can't seem to get the sums to match

```
>>> df_c = df_a.merge(df_b, how='left', on='id')
>>> df_c['sum_c'] = df_c['sum_b']
>>> df_c = df_c.drop(['sum_a', 'sum_b'], axis=1)
>>> df_a_group = df_c.groupby(['id', 'cat_a'], as_index=False)['sum_c'].sum().reset_index(drop=True)
>>> print(df_a)
  id   cat_a  sum_a
0  A    blue    800
1  B    blue    500
2  B   green    500
3  C  yellow    550
4  D     red   1000
>>> print(df_a_group)
  id   cat_a  sum_c
0  A    blue    800
1  B    blue   1000
2  B   green   1000
3  C  yellow    550
4  D     red   1000
```

Comment: hint, you can use `DataFrame.merge` to do a "left" join, another hint, you don't actually need to keep values from `sum_a`, since `sum_b` already adds up to `sum_a`

Comment: please do try to come up with some code of your own, and update it in your question. If you still don't get it, let me know :)

Comment: @LiewXun, Thanks so much for the hints :) I tried left merge on 'id', and used 'sum_b" as 'sum_c', however it doesn't look the same sums after the final groupby (I added my attempt above). I will continue trying and see if I make any progress. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can merge both dataframes:

```
df_c = df_a.merge(df_b, on = 'id', how = 'outer')
df_c['sum_c'] = df_c.apply(lambda x: x['sum_b']/2 if x['id'] == 'B' else x['sum_b'], axis = 1)
```

If your data looks different, you just need to compute how to distribute the sums. In your example it is only necessary for id B.

Comment: No, it is wrong, do you test it?

Comment: I did test it and I was confused why there is no blue triangle for id B. It is not really explained in the question.

Comment: hmmm, for me is perfectly clear - need redistibute sums between categories by `id`.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear - I have tried rewriting. Can confirm this solution works here, although I am hoping to find a more general solution as I will likely need to apply this to much messier data later. Thanks!